# Actionscript - Expanding circle - Performance issues

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, drawing, graphics2d

I'm trying to create an expanding circle for several reasons. For testbed, i'm using actionscript to develop the start for it.

This is the code i have so far:

EDIT

*UPDATED CODE 13.39 GMT+1 - Updated code again*

*UPDATED CODE 14.54 GMT+1 - Updated code, now runs pretty fluently, thanks to Vesper for his help*

Main.as

```
package  
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import Wavelet;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    var startColor:Number = 0x00AA00;
    var particleBitmapdata:BitmapData;
    var m_temptimer:int;

    private var myVector:Vector.<Wavelet> = new Vector.<Wavelet>();
    public function Main() 
    {
        // constructor code         
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    public function init(evt:Event)
    {
        particleBitmapdata = new BitmapData(3,3,false, startColor);

        var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(100, 0);
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, run);
        myTimer.start();
    }

    public function run(tevt:TimerEvent)
    {
        for(var i:int=0; i < 360; i+=1)
        {
            myVector.push(new Wavelet(3, 1, i, startColor,particleBitmapdata));
            myVector[myVector.length-1].x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            myVector[myVector.length-1].y = stage.stageHeight/2;
            addChild(myVector[myVector.length-1]);
        }

    }

    public function update(evt:Event)
    {
        var time:int = getTimer();
        var dt:Number = (time - m_temptimer) * 0.001;
        m_temptimer = time;

        for(var i:int=0; i < myVector.length-1; i++)
        {
            var w:Wavelet = myVector[i];

            if(w.x > stage.stageWidth || w.x < 0  )
            {
                removeChild(myVector[i]);
                myVector[i] = null;
                myVector.splice(i,1);
            }
            if(w.y > stage.stageHeight || w.y < 0 )
            {
                removeChild(myVector[i]);
                myVector[i] = null;
                myVector.splice(i,1);
            }

        }

        for(var j:int=0; j < myVector.length; j++)
        {
            myVector[j].update(dt);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Wavelet.as

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.filters.*;
import flash.geom.*;

public class Wavelet extends Bitmap
{
    private var m_velocity:Number;
    private var m_angle:Number;
    private var m_radius:Number;
    private var m_bmd:BitmapData;
    private var m_color=0x0000FF;
    private var m_angleX,m_angleY;

    public function getAngle():Number
    {
        return m_angle;
    }


    public function getVelocity():Number
    {
        return m_velocity;
    }

    public function setVelocity(input:Number)
    {
        m_velocity = input;
    }

    public function Wavelet(radius:int, velocity:Number, angle:Number, color:Number, bitmapData:BitmapData)
    {
        // constructor code
        m_radius = radius;
        m_angle = angle * Math.PI / 180 ;
        m_velocity = velocity;
        m_angleX = Math.cos(angle);
        m_angleY = Math.sin(angle);
        m_color = color;
        m_bmd = bitmapData;
        this.bitmapData = m_bmd;
    }

    public function update(dt:Number)
    {
        this.x+= m_angleX * m_velocity;
        this.y+= m_angleY * m_velocity;
        m_velocity+=dt;
    }
}

}
```

Anyhow, The performance I am getting out of it is terrible terrible slow.
I don't want to create an expanding circle as a whole, i need the pixels in order to calculate when they are colliding with walls and objects, to make them change direction.

Is there anyway you can make an exanding circle with better performance?

Comment: Made the first fix myself, by not using internal update listeners in each Wavelet object, but instead handling the position update from Main.as, but the performance is still quite bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited due to updated code.

First, you can put all the wavelet move routine into the `Wavelet` class, as well as pre-cache  `Math.sin(angle)` and `Math.cos(angle)` into `vx` and `vy` variables in the class. This will save you 720 `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` calls per circle run.

Second, you are splicing a particle on the forward loop - in this case the particle right next in your vector will not move when the one prior to it will get spliced. This is a common bug, but mostly it ends up worse, if i'th element is queried past `splice()`, thus getting null exception.

And third, you are requesting `myVector[i]` a dozen times within your loop - this request is not cached in the code, so instead you do this: `var w:Wavelet=myVector[i];` and address everything via `w` pointer, it makes a slight performance increase, as Flash doesn't need to constantly check for out-of-bounds issue or retrieve a list element.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that got removed all together when i moved the update routine from the Wavelet object to Main instead (see the comment above)

Comment: Please update the code in the question, then. Perhaps there's another performance tip that is shaded by reallocating BDs.

Comment: @Hiam okay, edited the answer. Perhaps this will amp performance a bit.

Comment: Yeah, what you are suggesting makes sense. I've updated the code with the suggestions you've made.

Still does not run "that" fluently... I wonder if there is anything else that is the main problem here.

Comment: You don't need `w` to be class-wide variable, as you are using it only in `update()` function. Declare it in there, it's the proper place for a temporary variable.

Comment: It is proper sure, but you are also running to code equal to binding the variable to a register in the interpreter. I'm using global, to skip the registry bind, until i can figure out the performance issues.

Comment: I'm starting to believe it's a combined issue with how the pixels move according to what we expect them to move each frame...

Comment: Yep, that was the case. I've updated my new code. It works pretty sweet. Thanks Vesper for the assistance!